# Storing SSL sessions in Android

Tags: android, ssl

Im pretty new to SSL, however in making an SSL request, how would i prevent the "handshake" happening each time i call an HTTPS url in Android. Is it possible to just store the SSL session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you making your requests?  Are you seeing separate handshakes for every new request to a particular host and how frequently?

I would think that the underlying security libraries on Android, much like Sun's JSSE, would automatically cache the TLS session ID when you're working with a particular host.

Comment: Android webview doesn't seem to cache the session ID. And as a result there's a new handshake everytime. But strangely requests made in intervals less than ~5s seems to work without handshake. Any idea?